# where can I find the ControlTemplate for DatePickerTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Can anybody give me a ControlTemplate for DatePickerTextBox?

I have visited MSDN. There I am not able to find ControlTemplate for DatePickerTextBox. However I was able to find ControlTemplate for DatePicker. There I just found that DatePickerTextBox has two different parts namely : **PART_Watermark** and **PART_ContentElement**. But I am not able to find a ControlTemplate for DatePickerTextBox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636310/custom-wpf-datepickertextbox-template-help

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have visited that link before asking this question. There I cannot find the full ControlTemplate. Both of the above mentioned parts namely PART_Watermark and PART_ContentElement are not present in that Template.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Also, my primary need here is to change the Watermarked text as well as the Date separator from `/` to `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes default template for **`DatePickerTextBox`**:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush
                x:Key="G">#FFAAAAAA</SolidColorBrush>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup
                Name="CommonStates" />
            <VisualStateGroup
                Name="WatermarkStates" />
            <VisualStateGroup
                Name="FocusStates" />
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
            CornerRadius="1,1,1,1"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
            Name="Border"
            Opacity="1">
            <Grid
                Name="WatermarkContent"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}">
                <Border
                    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                    BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF"
                    Name="ContentElement" />
                <Border
                    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                    BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF"
                    Name="watermark_decorator">
                    <ContentControl
                        Padding="2,2,2,2"
                        Name="PART_Watermark"
                        Opacity="0"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Focusable="False" />
                </Border>
                <ScrollViewer
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    Name="PART_ContentHost"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                <Border
                    CornerRadius="1,1,1,1"
                    BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA"
                    Name="FocusVisual"
                    Opacity="0"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: If the above mentioned template is default, then why can't I find the default watermark text saying `Select a date` in that template?

Comment: When you add `DatePickerTextBox` you get default text `<Enter text here>` (atleast in windows 8) and that comes from `VisualStateGroup` called `WatermarkStates` which must be defined in theme style in `PresentationFramework` assembly.

Comment: There are two separate controls `DatePickerTextBox` and one `DatePicker`. Which one you want?

Comment: I want to use DatePicker control. I think DatePicker uses DatePickerTextBox in its control Template as mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So, I need to change the watermark text and Date Separator for DatePickerTextBox.

Comment: Most likely it comes from VisualStates. However for setting custom text, have you tried the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1102073/632337)?

Comment: OK, I tried that. There he mentioned that I should use Watermark Property instead of Text Property. But I cannot find Watermark Property on DatePickerTextBox.

Comment: That's readonly property like said in the answer. Setting Text doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes setting text works for me but The text is then selectable.

Comment: Still I am marking this as answer as my needs are satisfied. I wanted a template and you provided me one. Plus point of your provided template is that it completely removes the watermarked text. Thanks Rohit.

Comment: Watermark property is readOnly so you cannot set it from outside. However, you can create attached beahvior and set the content manually for waterMarkTextBox. This will work for you - [Set watermark from XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5887276/632337).

Comment: Or create your own DatePicker control and override `OnApplyTemplate` like described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/05/06/changing-the-watermark-text-in-a-datepicker-control.aspx). In both cases jest is to set manually content value of WaterMarkTextBox.

Comment: And 1 more thing can you say how do I change DateSeparator from `/` to `.`?

Comment: `DatePicker` control picks the pattern from `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. You need to override CurrentCulture DateTimeFormat but that will change date format for all controls and dateTime object. Otherwise you want it for your own control, try the attached behavior like described here - (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12993259/632337) (not tested though).