# How to place cursor in the first position of a Datepicker control in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, .net-4.5

I have a datepicker control on a wpf form (masked as 00-00-0000). If the datepicker is empty, then I want the cursor always to be in the first position no matter where I click on the datepicker textbox. I tried using SelectionStart property (set to 0) on MouseDown event but it didn't work. Can anyone please give an idea? Please let me know if you need more info. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried for example doing the same thing like you would with a TextBox.. determine the length,then based on the difference set the focus / SelectionStart.. if worse comes to worse do a google search

Comment: The underlying textbox can do the job, you might want to check out this [Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636310/custom-wpf-datepickertextbox-template-help) in order to know how to change the TextBox's behavior.

Comment: I don't give thumbs down so not sure what you mean by that..all I did was make a suggestion.. so with that being said.. can you show some actual code as to what you have tried.. thanks

Comment: @Ranud - Thanks for the suggestion. Did learn a few stuff about datepicker from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should find `TextBox` element and subscribe to event `PreviewMouseUp`.

1) Add `DatePicker` with `Loaded` event:

```
<DatePicker Name="myDatePicker" Loaded="MyDatePicker_OnLoaded" />
```

2) Find `TextBox` element (in the `DatePicker` type of the text box element is `DatePickerTextBox`) and subscribe to `PreviewMouseUp`:

```
private void MyDatePicker_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (DatePickerTextBox)myDatePicker.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", myDatePicker);
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.PreviewMouseUp += (s, args) =>
        {
            tb.CaretIndex = 0;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: @kmatyzaszek - THAT worked so well!! Thanks so much!! Awesome answer. I was always trying to do it on Mousedown using SelectionStart and CaretIndex (set to 0) but was not working. Thanks again.

Comment: @kmatyzaszek I just noticed something while doing more testing. When I load up the form and touch/click on the textbox of datepicker field for the very first time , the mouseup event does fire but the cursor does not move to the first position. It moves on the second time I click on the textbox and then it keeps working fine. Initially it seemed to work may be because I double-clicked on the datepicker textbox control somehow. Just as a side note, I saw that setting caretindex=0 on just a PreviewMouseUp event works same as the one your solution.

Comment: I got around the issue now. Setting the caretindex to 0 on LostMouseCapture event of parttextbox (DatePickerTextBox) does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void DatePicker_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)sender;
        switch (true) {
            case true when (!"0123456789/.,".Contains(e.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)):
            case true when (dp.Text.Count(c => c == ',') > 1 && e.Text == ".")://Eingabe Komma
            case true when (dp.Text.Count(c => c == ',') > 0 && e.Text == "/"):
            case true when (dp.Text.Count(c => c == '.') > 0 && e.Text == "/")://Wenn Komme UND / eingegeben werden ...
            case true when (dp.Text.Count(c => c == '/') > 0 && e.Text == "."):
            case true when (dp.Text.Count(c => c == '.') > 1 && e.Text == "."):// Wenn mehr Punkte oder / eingegeben werden ... 
            case true when (dp.Text.Count(c => c == '/') > 1 && e.Text == "/"):
                e.Handled = true; break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (e.Text ==",") {
            var tb = (DatePickerTextBox)dp.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", dp);
            if (tb != null) {
                int pos = tb.CaretIndex;
                tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(tb.CaretIndex, ".");
                tb.CaretIndex = pos + 1;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is in English, but your comments are in German.

Comment: Try to avoid code-only answers. Please provide some extra information and/or context that will explain what you've written here.